# android - transparent activity that don't blocks mobile home screen events

Tags: android, android-activity

Is it possible to create activity that don't blocks other applications?
I created a transparent activity (like popup)
In the middle there is an image and the background is transparent . so far so Good.
But i want to let the user to click other apps while my activity is open
Is it possible?

I use: getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE);
But i can't click on the home screen apps.
Thanks

Comment: you can pass any event from the child view to the parent view ,but i dont think you can pass any event from one app to another

Comment: I don't want to pass event from another app.
I just want to let other app work while my activity is steel on

Comment: i think that's impossible because when you open your app another apps will go in background ,unless you make your app as a small app.

Comment: what you mean - small app ?

Comment: Instead of using a transparent activity, you can use WindowManager and add views to the screen (just like facebook messenger)

Comment: small apps like what sony provide (screen capture or small calculator) or you can use @Simar solution

Comment: sound perfect i will check it out